# Build cpp-netlib fail - not adding lib prefix

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cygwin, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to build cpp-netlib using cmake from cygwin.
However cmake try to find the package without the `lib` prefix. And `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON` won't resolve the problem!

Here is my command line:

```
cmake ../cpp-netlib-0.9.4/ -DBOOST_ROOT:string=/cygdrive/c/Dev/boost_1_55_0 -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DBoost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG=ON
```

The searching:

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_55;boost_thread-gcc48-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_55;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-gcc48-mt-d-1_55;boost_thread-gcc48-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d-1_55;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt-1_55;boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_55;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt-d-1_55;boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_55;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-gcc48-mt-1_55;boost_program_options-gcc48-mt;boost_program_options-mt-1_55;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-gcc48-mt-d-1_55;boost_program_options-gcc48-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt-d-1_55;boost_program_options-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
```

Here is the full result: http://pastebin.com/ZBfQyWvw.

As you can see in the command line I'm using cpp-netlib 0.9.4 and Boost 1.55.0.

Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give the name and full path of one of the Boost libs which definitely exists on your machine, and which you're expecting CMake to find please?

Comment: Yes, sure. The libs are located at C:\Dev\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib (or /cygdrive/c/Dev/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib). The full listing is here: http://pastebin.com/6uk5pv3s. However I have seen another problem when you ask me it. The libboost files are vc120, and CMake from cpp-netlib is expecting gcc48...

Comment: Forgetting cygwin, I downloaded CMake and OpenSSL versions for Windows and built it using command prompt. Everything worked fine now. However I'm having some problems on build the solution. I need to change something on the project or I just need to open the .sln and build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Boost libraries have been built with MSVC specified as the compiler (the "-vc120-" in their names is the telltale).  With Cygwin, you need to build for Unix variants.

From the note at the top of Boost's [build instructions for Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html):

> A note to Cygwin and MinGW users
>
> If you plan to use your tools from the Windows command prompt, you're in the right place. If you plan to build from the Cygwin bash shell, you're actually running on a POSIX platform and should follow the instructions for [getting started on Unix variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). Other command shells, such as MinGW's MSYS, are not supported—they may or may not work.

You can see that CMake's FindBoost module is doing the right thing; guessing that the compiler is GCC.  For example, line 62 of your linked CMake output is:

> -- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8.11.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:739 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc48

Comment: Perfect, that was my problem. Use CMake and OpenSSL for Windows and build using command prompt fix the issue. Trying to build the solution now but I think it is another topic. :)